# How to apply INNER JOIN ON certain condition

Tags: mysql, join

This is how my table stored data:
[image]

See that I want to select the text(name) for the id from respective tables for displaying purpose.

*Ignore the spelling mistake for clasification
Here I join with roles table for role_name(column), 
clasification table for name(column) and 
object table for name(column).

In my above table, there are '0' seen for both classi_id and object_id. So using my inner join statement it only returns two rows which does not have '0' value.

I want to put a condition in my query where it only INNER JOIN on clasificationa nd object table for those rows that does not have '0' value but I expect to return all 5 rows with respective roles.role_name, clasification.name and object.name.

Please check my query below:

*I'm using database wrapper for this query

```
$data = $this->db->select("SELECT * FROM role_linkto INNER JOIN roles ON role_linkto.role_id = roles.role_id INNER JOIN clasification ON role_linkto.classi_id = clasification.id INNER JOIN object ON role_linkto.object_id = object.id ");

return $data;
```

linkto_id [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaZc6.png)
 -role_name [Super_Admin]
 -classification.name[System]
linkto_id [2]
 -role_name [Agency_Admin]
 -classification.name[Agency]
linkto_id [3]
 -role_name [Contract_Admin]
 -classification.name[Department]
 -object.name[Contract]
linkto_id [4]
 -role_name [Contract_Owner]
 -object.name[Contract]
linkto_id [5]
 -role_name [Supplier]
 -classification.name[Agency]
 -object.name[Contract]

Comment: I think you might be looking for a `LEFT JOIN` since you want to keep all your 5 rows and apply extra conditions. Can you place the result you want in the question too?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen, added expected result in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do left Join with conditions on the 2 tables with 0s

```
"SELECT * FROM role_linkto INNER JOIN roles ON role_linkto.role_id = roles.role_id LEFT JOIN clasification ON role_linkto.classi_id = clasification.id AND clasification.id <> '0' LEFT JOIN object ON role_linkto.object_id = object.id AND object.id <>'0' "
```